# Magento 1.7 Nginx PHp-FPM PDF Invoices

Tags: magento-1.7, nginx, pdf

Ok I've been googling like a possessed person and I can't find anything that helps with this.

We've been running Magento on an NGINX setup nicely for some time but we am stuck on solving an issue with admin based pdf invoices not working.

Nothing in logs - nginx error logs. Only thing I see in Magento exception log is:

`[notice] 19794#0: 3321688 "^(..php)/" matches "/index.php/admin/sales_invoice/pdfinvoices/key/**/“, client: , server: **.com, request: "POST /index.php/admin/sales_invoice/pdfinvoices/key/**/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.domain.com", referrer: "https://www.domain.com/index.php/admin/sales_invoice/index/key/**/"`


`9794#0: 3321688 rewritten data: "/index.php", args: "", client: 109.*, server: **.com, request: "POST /index.php/admin/sales_invoice/pdfinvoices/key/**/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.domain.com", referrer: "https://www.domain.com/index.php/admin/sales_invoice/index/key/**/"`

I'm wondering if the fact that in the second block the args are empty has anything to do with it, but if that was the case I would expect some form of error instead of a white screen.

I've tried upping PHP memory limits, execution times, time-out limits but to no avail and I still can't get an error logged anywhere. I read (link not to hand) that someone in an earlier version of Magento had a similar error because they were using fast-cgi, switching away from this not a realistic option currently.

Any suggestions on what else to look at, or anyone come across this and have a fix? My gut says it's a nginx/php-fpm tweak that needs to be made but struggling to find it.

Magento 1.7
PHP 5.3.17
Nginx 1.2.3

Cheers,

Adam

Comment: Define "is not working"? Did you crank up php-fpm loglevel? What's in /var/log/php-fpm5.log ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic due to inactivity from OP.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic due to inactivity from OP.